# How to launch an activity from browser automatically?

Tags: android, android-activity, browser

There's an activity in my app.

```
<activity android:name=".FromWebActivity"
      android:exported="true"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="test"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

A function named openNative in my HTML.

```
var openNative = function(location) {
var iframeDom = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframeDom.src = location;
    iframeDom.height = 0;
    iframeDom.width = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(iframeDom);
};

openNative("test://account");
```

And an a tag in this html too.

```
<a href="test://account">open my app</a>
```

When browser open this page, some devices(ZTE S291 android 4.3) can launch my app automatically. The others devices(Nexus 5 android 4.4.4; Nexus 6 android 5.0.1) can't. I have to click the  tag manually to launch my app. Why?

When I visit this page, I want to open my app automatically. How can I do that? Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

STEP 1: Create an activity which will open your main activity using

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
finish();
```

STEP 2: Declare activity created above in Manifest file

```
<activity
        android:name="com.OpenMainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="test" />
            <data android:host="account" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Feel free to revert for any query.

Comment: If you have added the functionality to do the task on tag click, it will do so on tag click.